# Trying to regex all capitalized words EXCEPT those immediately following a period in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, cpu-word

I'm trying to have a bot crawl through text and absorb with a high degree of accuracy all proper nouns/phrases. So anything capitalized in the middle of a sentence, where anything capitalized in succession is considered part of the same phrase (and list entry).

So far I have:

```
tag_string = re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([a-zA-Z]+)', in_string)
```

Which has trouble with proper nouns immediately preceding periods. Also takes surrounding lowercase words.

And I also have:

```
#tag_string = re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)(\s([a-zA-Z]+)|\.)', in_string)
```

Which takes even more surrounding lowercase words but is less susceptible to the preceding period issue. I've been at this for hours. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<!\.)[A-Z][a-z]+` https://regex101.com/r/UvqJLo/1

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to match everything being sure to match the period. Then you can filter out all the matches that contain a period.

Something like this `\.? *[A-Z][a-z]*`

Then you can filter out the offending matches.

```
import re

out = re.findall('\.? *[A-Z][a-z]*', 'This is a sentence. This is Another sentence.   And this is a anoth.er Hello')
outFil = [x for x in out if x[0] != '.']
print(out, outFil)
```

> ['This', '. This', ' Another', '.   And', ' Hello']
>
> ['This', '
>   Another', ' Hello']